# How to map object to single value from this object?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection

I want to map object property **user** to its name.
I'm trying to map it like that, but it's doesn't change anything.

**My code for getting results:**

```
$data = $stats
    ->with('user')
    ->get()
    ->map(function ($value, $key) {
        $value['user'] = $value['user']['name'];
        return $value;
    });
```

**Current resulted data:**

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "total": 4,
            "user": {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "test1"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Desired result:**

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "total": 4,
            "user": "test1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this work, inside your map function: `return $value['user']['name']`

Comment: @erickb your code gives me only array of each user name without total, so that's not it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
$data = $stats
    ->with('user')
    ->get()
    ->map(function ($value, $key) {
        return [
            'total' => $value['total'],
            'user' => $value['user']['name'],
        ];
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$data = $stats
    ->with('user')
    ->get()
    ->map(function ($value, $key) {
        $userName = $value['user']['name'];
        unset($value['user']);
        $value['user'] = $userName;
        return $value;
    });
```